# custom validations with custom control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, custom-controls

I have a custom web control which has two html select field and buttons i use them to make associated and available list box.But in few situations i have to Validate that Associated field must have at least 1 entity. I implemented a client side custom validator to confirm that. and its working great but issue is i am unable to fire Validate at the time List box is made empty it fires when i click save button and similarly when i have moved a few entries in associated List. validation Message is stile there and removes only when i click save button.

So i want to know how can i fire validator when i need using javascript...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fire a validator from javascript we may use `ValidatorValidate(document.getElementById('validator clientID'))`

for more details see http://fczaja.blogspot.in/2009/07/aspnet-how-to-trigger-client-side.html